# Not able to figure out where to put float:left; in the code

Tags: html, css

> I have put few product images in my shopping website and now I want them aligned one after the other. Please help me put float:left; property correctly through the code. I have used inline CSS.

```
 <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">

 <div>
 <div>
 <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Oo0cN4TKxYY/VLpaQmWWYOI/AAAAAAAAAiE/HYEWlvr7Lrw/s1600/3-little-s-deluxe-gift-set-400x400-imae3r6szgnxh7wj.jpeg" 

 width="98px"/>
 </div>

 <div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 window.open("http://www.amazon.com/little-s-deluxe-gift-set/p/itmdapwqfgaczsrz?pid=BBCDAHZMPHRHVVYG&otracker=from-search&srno=t_5&query=baby+care&ref=9584cc4b-1511-454f-8ade-ec58babb4503","_self")
 }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>








 <div>
 <div>
 <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IlWU11ibyeg/VLpaQYbc8WI/AAAAAAAAAiI/Gnk7aEJbt9E/s1600/8-johnsons-baby-care-collection-400x400-imadngre8pbkrrsw.jpeg" height="98px" 

 width="98px"/>
 </div>

 <div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 window.open("http://www.amazon.com/johnsons-baby-care-collection/p/itmdnzg5zzugsnfm?pid=BBCDC2MZ95CZGEGG&otracker=from-search&srno=t_2&query=johnsons+baby+care&ref=9d0a902a-012a-4831-8379-40325f9b2da5
","_self")
  }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think I provided the solution to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I've done was add **style="float:left"** to both parent divs - Demo on jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfrap2dL/

```
 <div dir="ltr" style="text-align: left;" trbidi="on">

 <div style="float:left">
 <div>
 <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Oo0cN4TKxYY/VLpaQmWWYOI/AAAAAAAAAiE/HYEWlvr7Lrw/s1600/3-little-s-deluxe-gift-set-400x400-imae3r6szgnxh7wj.jpeg" 

 width="98px"/>
 </div>

 <div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 window.open("http://www.amazon.com/little-s-deluxe-gift-set/p/itmdapwqfgaczsrz?pid=BBCDAHZMPHRHVVYG&otracker=from-search&srno=t_5&query=baby+care&ref=9584cc4b-1511-454f-8ade-ec58babb4503","_self")
 }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>
 <div style="float:left">
 <div>
 <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-IlWU11ibyeg/VLpaQYbc8WI/AAAAAAAAAiI/Gnk7aEJbt9E/s1600/8-johnsons-baby-care-collection-400x400-imadngre8pbkrrsw.jpeg" height="98px" 

 width="98px"/>
 </div>

 <div>
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function myFunction() {
 var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
 window.open("http://www.amazon.com/johnsons-baby-care-collection/p/itmdnzg5zzugsnfm?pid=BBCDC2MZ95CZGEGG&otracker=from-search&srno=t_2&query=johnsons+baby+care&ref=9d0a902a-012a-4831-8379-40325f9b2da5
","_self")
  }
  </script>
  </div>
  </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: absolutely, you are a superstar. please help me give some space between  the two products.

Comment: @androidrill add "padding-right:10px" in the inline-CSS elements. So, it'll be like: style="float:left;padding-right:10px" (or whatever number of pixels  - px - you want)

Comment: @androidrill give this poor fellow the Answer checkmark :P I hope it worked well though!

Comment: you are the star. you earned it!